# Finitely-generated amenable group isomorphic to its square

Tags: gr.group-theory

> Is there a nontrivial finitely-generated amenable group isomorphic to its square?

I'm also fine with $G$ being just a direct summand of itself if it's easier and if the other group is infinite (equivalently nontrivial, as pointed out by @YCor). I know that the Grigorchuk group is a near miss to being isomorphic to its square, being commensurable to its square.

I also know that there are nontrivial finitely-generated groups isomorphic to their squares. Jones constructs one in [1]. If I understand the structure correctly, it starts with an amalgamated free product $S = F_2 *_G F_2$ for some suitable $G$, and then constructs a suitable subgroup of $S^{\mathbb{N}}$. An amalgamated free product of nonamenable groups is not amenable since the vertex groups are embedded, and $S^{\mathbb{N}}$ can also be nonamenable even when $S$ is amenable. I didn't really understand this construction so I don't know what properties are really needed.

There's also Meier's construction [2] where you start instead with a finitely-generated simple group $S$ containing a non-Hopfian subgroup. Finitely-generated amenable simple groups exist, but I don't know if they can contain non-Hopfian subgroups. Furthermore, even if they can, this construction also constructs (a subgroup of) $S^{\mathbb{N}}$. For all f.g. simple amenable groups $S$ that I'm aware of, $S^{\mathbb{N}}$ is non-amenable, so one would have to see if the specific subgroup stays amenable.

Finally there's Baumslag-Miller [3] but similar comments apply as in the case of [1].

[1] *Tyrer Jones, J. M.*, [**Direct products and the Hopf property**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S144678870001675X), J. Aust. Math. Soc. 17, 174-196 (1974). [ZBL0286.20040](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0286.20040).

[2] *Meier, David*, [**Non-Hopfian groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s2-26.2.265), J. Lond. Math. Soc., II. Ser. 26, 265-270 (1982). [ZBL0504.20016](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0504.20016).

[3] *Baumslag, Gilbert; Miller, Charles F. III*, [**Some odd finitely presented groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/blms/20.3.239), Bull. Lond. Math. Soc. 20, No. 3, 239-244 (1988). [ZBL0646.20029](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0646.20029).

Comment: A side remark is that if $G\times F$ is isomorphic to a quotient of $G$, with $G$ f.g. and $F$ finite then $F=1$.

Comment: @YCor: You mean, in particular the "other group" would automatically be infinite if nontrivial? I was wondering about that but I didn't see it.

Comment: Yes, and even that it has a trivial profinite completion. Indeed, it implies that the generating rank of $F^n$ is bounded independently of $n$. For $F$ finite this implies $F=1$. (Actually you can also see it as *corollary* of fg+rf implies Hopfian.)

Comment: Ok, if $G$ is $k$-generated, then so is $G \times F^n$ for all $n$. That took me longer than it should've.

Comment: About the question: before the Matui–Juschenko–Monod examples (2006,2012) of topological-full groups, there was no known example of a nontrivial fg aperiodic amenable group (aperiodic = with no nontrivial finite quotient). The examples that were then discovered are usually close to be simple, hence very far from being isomorphic to their own square, or even to a proper direct summand of themselves. I'm not sure one even knows a non-Hopfian aperiodic amenable fg group.

Comment: Hmm, if a group is f.g. amenable and isomorphic to its own direct summand, it is certainly non-Hopfian, but I don't see why it has to be aperiodic

Comment: No I didn't say this (and it's obviously false since $G$ isomorphic to a proper direct summand implies that $G\times\mathbf{Z}$ also). But if isomorphic to its own direct square, yes.

Comment: Ok, that I see (same argument). Thanks for the comments, this seems to be a hopeless problem then.

Comment: At least it seems to me that if $G$ is the derived subgroup of the topological-full group of a minimal subshift, then the generating rank of $G^n$ is bounded independently of $n$. So $G$ would be a plausible candidate for an isomorphism $H\simeq H\times G$.

Comment: Here's a dumb argument that I think proves $G^n$ has bounded rank when $G$ is simple and contains all finite groups (which is the case here). Pick a different (large) alternating group $A_{k_i}$ for each $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$, and pick generators $g_{i,1}, g_{i,2}$ for $A_{k_i}$. Take generators $(g_{1,1}, ..., g_{n, 1})$ and $(g_{1,2}, ..., g_{n,2})$ in $G^n$. By Goursat's lemma, these generate $A_{k_1} \times A_{k_2} \times \cdots A_{k_n}$. So by simplicity these plus the diagonal generators give you $G^n$.

Comment: Oh, I think Your argument works only assuming that $G$ is f.g. simple and contains elements of arbitrary large prime order ($G^n$ is then generated by the diagonal and $(g_1,\dots,g_n)$ whenever the $g_i$ have distinct prime order).

Comment: Right, there's many ways to get something in just one component, yours is much better. Now what's $H$...

Comment: @Ycor I think I'm missing an argument to go from "alternating groups" to "prime order". Is it clear that any f.g. [infinite] simple group $G$ is generated by two elements?

Comment: ARG you use the prime group as an analog of the alternating group in my argument. Simplicity of the big groups is used for something else. (Surely not every simple group is 2-generated.)

Comment: @ARG: I didn't say $G$ is generated by 2 elements. I said $G^n$ is generated by the diagonal plus one element. So if $G$ is generated by $k$ elements then $G^n$ is generated by $k+1$ elements regardless of $n$. (When $G$ is simple f.g. with elements of arbitrary large prime order.)

Comment: As discussed, the question about 2-generation of simple groups is irrelevant, nevertheless the answer is "no": https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00969195

Comment: @Ycor thanks, just wanted to make sure I didn't miss something: but in your comment there was only two elements explicitly mentioned "the diagonal and (...)", which is why I wanted to make sure. ->Ville Salo: sure enough it is irrelevant, but it's better to ask. Unless I'm misunderstood the aim of this forum?

Comment: To clarify, I don't suggest you made any mistake, I'm saying that your question about 2-generation turned out not to be needed to resolve your confusion about YCor's argument. Nevertheless, I thought it was a good question in itself, so I looked for a reference (actually took me some time to find that).

Comment: @VilleSalo thanks, much appreciated.  (I actually wanted to look if there are amenable groups of the like [e.g. an infinite simple amenable whose 2-generated subgroups are all finite, but I was not patient enough to go through the litterature]) My confusion about YCor's argument was due to the lack of plural in "diagonal". So my reading was "one diagonal element and the (...)", and, though not necessary to resolve that confusion, my question did naturally emerge from it and hence [hopefully] gives information on the source of the confusion. Your question is a really fun question btw!