# Can a finitely presented group $G$ be isomorphic to its own square?

Tags: gr.group-theory

Does there exist a nontrivial finitely presented group $G$ such that $G \cong G^2$? I noticed a similar question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380680/finitely-generated-amenable-group-isomorphic-to-its-square), but it seems that the finitely generated groups discussed there are not finitely presented. Failing an example, is there a proof that no such $G$ exists? Thank you.

Comment: Up to my knownledge, this well-known problem is still open.

Comment: @AGenevois Thank you for responding. I am glad to hear it is well-known. If you or anyone else knows of a source that discusses this problem I would greatly appreciate a reference to it.

Comment: https://berstein2015.wordpress.com/2015/04/18/a-group-with-a-quotient-isomorphic-to-the-direct-square/ may be of interest.

Comment: @AGenevois Wonderful, thank you!

Comment: (It's better avoid asking a question and its negative, as answering yes/no becomes ambiguous... of course, if the answer to the question is no, it means that there is a proof that it doesn't exist, so the last opposite question is quite redundant.)

Comment: In Denis Osin's article "A topological zero-one law and elementary equivalence of ﬁnitely
generated groups", see https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2020.102915, it is proved that a finitely presented group satisfying $G \cong G\times G$ is necessarily extremely non-hopfian, meaning that for every ﬁnite subset $F \subset G$, there exists an non-injective epimorphism $G \to G$ whose restriction to $F$ is injective.